# MongoDB Replication Lag appears negative and positive for the same case in different shells

Tags: mongodb, replication, lag

When I run `db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()` on Primary Mongodb shell, I get positive replication lag. When I run `db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()` on Secondary Mongodb shell, I get Negative replication lag.

When I look at the code of MongoDB for `printSlaveReplicationInfo` in db.js file I get to see replication lag calculated as "Primary[OptimeDate] - Secondary[OptimeDate].

Data in Replication is copied from Primary to secondary. So isn't it obvious that Primary time is less than the secondary time ? Then why does Primary - Secondary time give positive value when I run `db.printSlaveReplicaionInfo()` on Primary Mongodb shell?

Comment: It will be good idea if you read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395430/mongodb-replica-set?rq=1)

Comment: @Chetan - I just edited your post - you write `db.printSlaveReplicationLag()` whereas the function you are running is actually called `db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()`

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the [great docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.printSlaveReplicationInfo/) on that function. A negative lag can sometimes be caused by [clock drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_drift) on your servers. Do you have an [NTP daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) active on those machines/? You can check your clocks by running `date`.

Again, from [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo/)

> [a negative value] is expected if the method is called after a
>   secondary replicates a write following a period of inactivity, but
>   before it has received a heartbeat from the primary with its latest
>   optime.

and

> For the most up-to-date information on your replica set, it is
>   generally advisable to run rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo() on the
>   primary.